# java with eclipse - lost design page

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am learning Java using Eclipse - started a project with javax.swing and could view a design page with my page layouts shown and various palets for components etc.   Now this design page seems to have vanished and I cant discover any option to recover it.  I hope someone can get me back on track.

Comment: Forgot to say that I started the project with WindowBuilder

Comment: Is the WindowBuilder plugin still installed? https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/

Comment: try right clicking your page in the project explorer and selecting a different editors from the list of editors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried Right-click on class (for example `MySwingPanel.java`) in package editor `Open With->WindowBuilder Editor`?

The last time you selected something in `Open With` - this is the editor to open that file on double click.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the Perspective? Click the arrows next to the DDMS tab in the upper right hand corner of Eclipse and select the 'Java' Perspective.